# How to get to "More details" for a view in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

In Sharepoint Online, when looking at the details pane for the "Pages" view, there is what appears to be a link to click for "More details":

[image: screenshot]

And looking at the HTML source, it appears to be a button. But it doesn't seem to do anything: I've tried it in multiple browsers. How do I get to see the "more details"?

**Update**

Turns out that this is just a non-functional UI element. My root problem was that I had accidentally created a private view, and I was trying to find the ACL for the view. Which I never did: ended up deleting this view and creating an identical public one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything to see for the "Site Pages" **folder**. I'm also not seeing anything. However, if you select a Page in the folder like Home.aspx, you can see the details info of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per my test in both Chrome and Edge, the “**More details**” in Site Pages doesn’t response when clicked and recent activities will be displayed directly under it. Just as Matiur Rahman suggests, you can check the specific page for details, and this "**More Details**" can be clicked to show or hide. If this is not your scenario, please let me know more information about your current situation.[image]

[image]

Comment: My situation is that some of my team can't see the new view I added, and I'm trying to figure out why. I hoped that the "More details" would include info about access rights to the view.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.Is there any update on your issue? The "More details" cannot be used to check the access.I would suggest you to create a new post with more details for help.